# Pandas return NaT when is should not

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame is

```
time  NTCS001G002  NTCS001W005
0  2013-05-30 23:00:00          NaN          NaN
1  2013-06-30 23:00:00          249           60
2  2013-07-31 23:00:00          161            2
3  2013-09-01 23:00:00          151           11
4  2013-09-04 23:00:00           14            0
5  2013-10-01 23:00:00          162           64
6  2013-11-01 00:00:00          281          175
7  2013-12-03 00:00:00          482          168
8  2014-01-02 00:00:00          378          NaN
9  2014-01-03 00:00:00          NaN          NaN
10 2014-02-03 00:00:00          NaN          167
11 2014-03-03 00:00:00          502          167
```

When I iterate the rows like
    for index, row in diffs.iterrows():
        print "err", row.tolist()

```
[12 rows x 3 columns]
err [Timestamp('2013-05-30 23:00:00', tz=None), NaT, NaT]
err [Timestamp('2013-06-30 23:00:00', tz=None), 249.0, 60.0]
err [Timestamp('2013-07-31 23:00:00', tz=None), 161.0, 2.0]
err [Timestamp('2013-09-01 23:00:00', tz=None), 151.0, 11.0]
err [Timestamp('2013-09-04 23:00:00', tz=None), 14.0, 0.0]
err [Timestamp('2013-10-01 23:00:00', tz=None), 162.0, 64.0]
err [Timestamp('2013-11-01 00:00:00', tz=None), 281.0, 175.0]
err [Timestamp('2013-12-03 00:00:00', tz=None), 482.0, 168.0]
err [Timestamp('2014-01-02 00:00:00', tz=None), 378.0, nan]
err [Timestamp('2014-01-03 00:00:00', tz=None), NaT, NaT]
err [Timestamp('2014-02-03 00:00:00', tz=None), nan, 167.0]
err [Timestamp('2014-03-03 00:00:00', tz=None), 502.0, 167.0]
```

I am not sure if those NaT are a bug or not. I think they should be NaN
Can Pandas be made not to return NaT and if not how could I check against them as I will have to replace them in the list.

Thanks

Comment: That's interesting -- row 10 has a `nan`, while row 9 has a `NaT`. Could you show how this DataFrame was defined? Naively loading your data using `pd.read_table` does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can reproduce with a simpler case.  I think this is leaking implementation details about exactly the way in which (as the docs say) "iterrows does **not** preserve dtypes across the rows".

Comment: You should show *why* you are iterating; e.g. what are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that iterrows makes each row into a Series, and this row is cast to datetime64....

```
In [11]: pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2014-01-03 00:00:00', tz=None), np.nan, np.nan])
Out[11]:
0   2014-01-03
1          NaT
2          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

The value `NaT` means "Not A Time", the equivalent of `nan` for timestamp values.

Can you tell the `dtypes` of your data frame? Try casting the columns to float values.